# how to use OR operator in Jenkins maven goal

Tags: maven, jenkins, cucumber-jvm

I'm using cucumber with selenium for UI automation.and using jenkin to schedule the job and maven for build management.
I'm using below maven command to run the project from windows command line which works perfectly fine.

```
mvn clean test || mvn clean -Dcucumber.options="@rerun.txt" test
```

Now I need to use this command to add in jenkins in maven build/goal section so using something like below

```
clean test || clean -Dcucumber.options="@rerun.txt" test
```

but the job fails with the below error 
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "||". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the

seems it doesn't accept OR(||) operator. any other way to use this command from jenkins

Comment: Try using single | for OR operator.

Answer (score 0):

The || in the shell basically says, if the thing on the left fails, then try the thing on the right. In a build job, you really want to be able to handle this a little more deliberately. You should create some logic in a pipeline job that tries `clean test`, catch the failure, and then execute the other half. Or for a freestyle job, you can probably do what you need with the conditional build step plugin, though I haven't used it much to know for sure.

Comment: yes, that's what i'm trying to achieve here, looks like have to use some plugin